# Django prefetch_related in loop, what is wrong?

Tags: django, django-models

i am trying to reduce the amount of queries in a Django app, but can't figure out how to do it the right way. I have a model with product all products has a default price, now I have a customerproduct with some customer related product prices

I am open for a redesign ;)

```
class Product(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    ....

    def get_prices(self, customer=None):
        '''
        get prices for the current product based on the price matrix given by bbp
        '''
        if customer:
            prices = self.get_customer_prices()
            if prices:
                self.price = self.customerproduct_set.filter(deleted=0).last().price

        return self

class CustomerProduct(AbstractProductPrice):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    ....
```

Now i want all products with related customer prices.

```
products = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('customerproduct_set')

    for product in products:
        product.get_prices(customer=1)
```

Prefetch is not "working" i don't understand how to use it.. please help.

I have 31 products in my db and django_debug_tool result in 35 queries.

Comment: You `filter` the `customerproduct_set`, A simple `.prefetch_related` only fetches the "`.all()`" so to speak. You can however construct a `Prefetch(..)` object that can prefetch a filtered set.

Comment: Wow, I didn't get that, can you give me an example ? ;)

Comment: But something is strange here? You query for the `.last()`? But you do not define an order, so that means it can return any (?) `CustomerProduct` that has `deleted=0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefetch `CustomerProducts` only for the customer you are interested in, then work with that result. Something like that:

```
products = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch(
        'customerproduct_set',
        queryset=CustomerProduct.objects.filter(customer=customer, deleted=0).order_by('id')
        to_attr='customer_prices'
    )
)

def get_product_prices(product):
    customer_prices = getattr(product, 'customer_prices', None)
    if customer_prices:
        return customer_prices[-1].price
    return product.price


for product in products:
    print get_product_prices(product)
```

Comment: Thanks ... i get an error .: local variable 'customer_prices' referenced before assignment

Comment: Well, don't blindly copy-paste untested code, try to understand it first... the reason for the error is because the second argument of  `getattr` is not encapsulated as a string, I'm gonna fix it right now.